# What is orbit that could place satellite to be always under the Sun?

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, satellites

I just thinking that, if we could place satellite to orbit earth in opposite direction of earth rotation, inverse of geostationary orbit. If we carefully choose a speed to sync with earth rotation, it would have that satellite stay exactly the same position in the sky as the sun

What is that altitude and are there any name of that orbit? Or is it just the same as geostationary orbit?

Comment: Look into sun-synchronous orbits. They are slightly retrograde, near-polar orbits, that use a Pacific mass concentration to perturb their orbits to rotate their orbital plane as the Earth travels around the sun. A large fraction of LEO satellites use them.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're talking about are Lagrangian points:

[image]

*Image Credit: Anynobody / Wikimedia Commons*

They are points such that the combined gravitational effects from the Earth and the Sun give rise to areas that would have the same angular velocity as the Earth. However, out of the five lagrange points shown below: 1,2,3 are unstable

You are probably referring to the first Lagrangian point, known as $L_1$ which is roughly $0.01$ AU away from Earth.

**Edit:** Turns out I misunderstood what you were asking for. If you were curious if such a point can exist such that it is still "orbiting" around the Earth, the answer is no. You may think that as the orbit goes further and further out, you can eventually reduce the period to one year. However, at this point the effect from the Sun cannot be ignored and you can't realy call it "orbiting" around Earth.

We have:

$$m\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)^2 r = \frac{GMm}{r^2} \to r^3 = \frac{GMT^2}{4\pi^2}$$

Plugging in $G=6.67\times 10^{-11} \mathrm{N\cdot m^2 \cdot kg^{-2}}$, $M=5.972 \times 10^{24} \text{ kg}$, and $T=31556926 \text{ s}$ gives:

$$r = 2.16 \times 10^9 \text{ m}$$

while $L_1$ is at a distance of 0.01 AU or $1.50 \times 10^9 \text{ m}$ which is slightly farther than the $L_1$ point which exists there due to the interaction between the Earth AND the Sun, so a satellite cannot orbit around Earth with a period of one year.

Comment: Note, though, that a satellite at the Lagrange point isn't "orbiting the Earth" in the same sense that a satellite in LEO or geostationary orbit is.  In those cases, the gravitational force from the Sun can be basically ignored;  but the existence of the Lagrange points depends critically on the forces from both the Sun and the Earth.  In other words, if the Sun didn't exist, the orbit described by the OP would be impossible.

Comment: Please properly credit the author of the diagram, which is from WP. This is required by the license and also by common courtesy.

Comment: @BenCrowell my bad, I added the appropriate credits now

Comment: The OP is asking about orbits around Earth though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert If the Sun did not exits, there would still be an orbit around the earth with a period of 1 year. It would be 5 times as far from the Earth than the L1 point is in reality though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Are you sure? I just did the calculations (see updated answer) and it seems like it won't 5 times as far.

Comment: I have just thinking simple. Suppose you drive a car or a plane from east to west with the sun over your head. There would be one angular speed that make a sun always above your head. And if we scale that westward path tobe satellite orbit, there should be some altitude that orbital velocity match that speed

Comment: @QiLinXue:  I had in mind an orbit that would always appear to be at the same position on the sky relative to the "fixed stars", as viewed from the Earth.  In a Universe where the Sun didn't exist (if Earth was a rogue planet, say), a one-year orbit could exist, as you've shown.  But the period wouldn't have any particular meaning without the Sun present.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be [geostationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit) because we would see it move across the sky. I think you mean [geosynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_orbit), which is what the orbit would almost be. If you wanted it to always stay in front of the sun from some special vantage point, then you would need to somehow have the satellite correct its orbit based on the changing tilt of the Earth.